# OpenVPN Tunnel Through IP-Restricted Modems

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have an OpenVPN server running on an untangle/ARISTA device (A). It has a site-to-site connection with another untangle/ARISTA device (B). Also connected to that (B) is an IP-restricted modem (B1). There is a similar modem (same IP restrictions; B2) off-site that has a third untangle/ARISTA device (C) that has a site-to-site cred for VPN server.

I've tried:
Port Forwarding 1194 thru modems B1 and B2.
Setting the B1 port on B to LAN and WAN.
Toggling NAT-ing traffic in the B1 port on B.

I haven't been able to get C to tunnel to A nor C to tunnel to B. Site B to A has a solid tunnel.

With the number of factors in the equation I'm struggling to the identify the individual problems, let alone the solution.

Comment: Please list each and all of the settings and variations in the config that you have tried. Show the detailed configurations for the networks at each site. Are you able to successfully from site A to B, and from site B to C, and vice versa? That is not clear in the question. Also, add all of this information to the question itself, not in comments down here.

Comment: @music2myear Notes added. and thank you for the feedback